# Почему объект равен null

Tags: c#, wpf, ооп

Есть простейший класс, не могу понять почему не могу сослаться на ранее созданный объект?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MyRepository MainRepo;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        MyRepository MainRepo = new MyRepository();
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = MainRepo;
    }        
    private void AddMyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        ....
        MainRepo.AddMy(TempMy);
     }
```

Почему MainRepo в обработчике нажатия равен null? При запуске программы с трассировкой - в метод MainWindow попадает, объект MainRepo создается

Comment: В приведенном коде возможной причины этого не видно, вы уверены, что проблема есть и ее не создаёт какой-то другой код, который здесь не показан?

Comment: Потому что вы этому полю никогда не присваиваете.

Comment: @АндрейNOP приглядитесь внимательнее: все тут хорошо видно...

Comment: Создаются две разные `MainRepo`, одна public в классе, а вторая локальная в конструкторе `MainWindow`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ах, да, локальная переменная же

Comment: Спасибо всем!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyRepository MainRepo = new MyRepository();
```

Т.к. вы указываете тип объекта, то MainRepo остается локальной для конструктора MainWindow

просто уберите MyRepository :

```
MainRepo = new MyRepository();
```

или сохраните референс в поле объекта (но это будет странное решение) :

```
MyRepository MainRepo = new MyRepository();
this.MainRepo = MainRepo;
```